# ReactJS: add data to document when creating a subcollection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to created documents and subcollections of documents like this:

[image: Structure]

So here is my code:

```
function Subscriptions() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const userProjectsColRef = collection(db, "users");
        const newProjectDocRef = doc(userProjectsColRef);
        addDoc(collection(newProjectDocRef, "experiences"), {
          name: "hello",
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
}
export default Subscriptions;
```

How can I add data to the very first document created (the "data" field with "bio", "fullname", "company") ?

Right now, this code does add a subcollection named "experiences" which has a document with some data (name: "hello"). Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two documents: firstly the parent `user` document and then
the `experience` document which `DocumentReference` is based on its parent doc's `DocumentReference` (i.e. `newProjectDocRef`).

```
const userProjectsColRef = collection(db, "users");
const newProjectDocRef = await addDoc(userProjectsColRef, {
  // ...
});
await addDoc(collection(newProjectDocRef, "experiences"), {
  // ...
});
```

---

Note that if you want those two writes to be done as an atomic operation, you should use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).